# How do I exchange object information during construction?

Tags: javascript, object

As a project to learn javascript I'm working on a small game.  In this game there are resources and machines.  Buying machines costs an amount of one or more resources, and each produces one or more resources.  Machines can also have an input, like energy, to keep producing.

Because of how resources and machines are intertwined, I'm not sure how to exchange information between them. To calculate the perSecond per resource, I don't want to loop through all machines to check if their output contains this resource. I'd rather construct the objects in such a way that only the machines producing this resource are examined.

I thought of a way of doing this by having the Machine constructor loop through its output object and push its name to an array in the resource's object. But somehow this *feels* more like a hack than a robust solution.  Added to this is that I'd like to come to a solution where new machines, (temporary) production boosts or discounts can be easily and dynamically applied by game mechanics I haven't worked out yet.  Where boosts and discounts can be per resource, per machine or all resources/machines.

Below is how I've currently defined the objects for resources and machines.

Do you have any advice or tips, please?

```
Game.objectConstructor.Resource = function(id, name) {

    var instance = {};
    instance.id = id;
    instance.name = name;
    instance.category = 'resource';

    var private = {};
    private.production = {
        perSecond: function() {
            // Go over all machines producing id and calculate
        },
        current: 0,
        update: function() {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            // Cap current storage by the maximum storage we have.
            private.production.current = Math.min(private.perSecond()/1000*(now-private.lastUpdate), private.storage.current());
        },
        lastUpdate: new Date().getTime(),
    },
    private.storage = {
        level: 1,
        baseCapacity: 50,
        discount: 0.00,
        upgradeCost: function() {
            var result = {};
            result[private.name] = private.storage.current()*(1-private.storage.discount);
            result['somethingelse'] = private.storage.current()*0.25*(1-private.storage.discount);
            return result;
        },
        current: function() {return Math.pow(private.storage.baseCapacity, private.storage.level);}
    }

    this.perSecond = function() {
        return private.production.perSecond();
    }

    return instance;
};

Game.materials.entries.metal = new Game.objectConstructor.Resource('metal', 'Metal');

Game.objectConstructor.Machine = function(id, name, cost, input, output) {

    var instance = {};
    instance.id = id;
    instance.name = name;
    instance.category = 'machine';

    var private = {};
    private.cost = cost;
    private.input = input;
    private.output = output;

    this.isAffordable = function() {
        if (Object.keys(private.cost).every(c => (c.current - cost[c]) > 0)) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    return instance;
}
Game.machines.entries.metalGrinder = new Game.objectConstructor.Machine('grinder', 'Grinder', {metal: 10}, {}, {metal: 1})
```

Comment: If ˋinputˋand ˋoutputˋ would be maps, you could directly reference the amount to the material, such as ˋoutput.set(Game.materials.entries.metal, 3)ˋ

Comment: @JonasW. Interesting, thank you.  I read up on maps after your reply, it seems I can easily translate the cost object in the function arguments to one by iterating over it.  This would work perfectly for new machines when all resources are defined already.  For the cost of storage upgrades I'll need to find another way, since at creation it can have a material as a cost that isn't created yet.

Comment: Why would it only work for new machines?   You could use instances of `Set` or just plain maps for all the resources a machine produces and add/remove from them dynamically.  Then do things like ... `var machines = [ .... ]; function machinesThatProduce(product) { return machines.filter( machine => machine,getOutput().has(product) ) }`

Comment: @Tibrogargan The difference is that when I'm creating machines, all resources are defined already.  So it's easy to: `
machines[machine].baseCost.add(resource.metal, 10) `
at creation.  In the meantime I reworked the storage upgrade so it works as a building instead of an upgrade that's part of the resource object.

Comment: If the collections of resources a machine uses are static and/or private then this would make sense, but nothing in the JavaScript language is enforcing this constraint - it's part of your design.  If you want to be able to add resources to a machine dynamically, the language supports doing that - but you would need to modify your design to take advantage of it.

Comment: @Tibrogargan That's a good point.  I hadn't given it any thought before that I could generate resources/machines when they unlock, instead of generating everything and hiding elements of unavailable items in the DOM.  I might need to rethink my concept.  Thanks!